# HyperVolume function not working in Python 3

Tags: python, deap

Based on a HyperVolume function found [**here**](https://ls11-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/rudolph/hypervolume/start) (direct download [link](https://ls11-www.cs.uni-dortmund.de/_media/rudolph/hypervolume/hv_python.zip)), I am trying to return hypervolume metrics for my algorithm. However, not even the test code works:

```
from hv import HyperVolume
referencePoint = [2, 2, 2]
hyperVolume = HyperVolume(referencePoint)
front = [[1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0]]
result = hyperVolume.compute(front)
```

I'm getting errors which seem to be related to the fact that I'm using Python 3, and the function itself is using Python 2. Is there a way around that? Is there a similar function implemented in Python 3?

I've also looked at [this one in deap](https://github.com/DEAP/deap/blob/master/deap/tools/_hypervolume/pyhv.py), but it seems the have the same issue.

LE: I've been asked for specific errors, so I'll keep a log of them as they're being solved

1. name xrange is not defined - fixed by replacing with range
2. [TypeError: unorderable types: Node() < Node()](https://gyazo.com/4201992829b71904bf6467a73129d7b4)

Comment: *I'm getting errors* Please [edit] your question and include them.

Comment: I can do, but it'll just be error after error, and I'll only be able to post them 1 at a time as they're being solved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 2to3 to convert hv.py to hv3.py:

```
$ 2to3 hv.py > hv3.py.patch
$ cp hv.py hv3.py
$ patch < hv3.py.patch
```

Then change your import line to

```
from hv3 import HyperVolume
```

If you want `2to3` to change the modify the original file, you need to pass the `-w` option, as shown in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#using-2to3)

```
$ 2to3 -w hv.py
```

Comment: I tried applying 2to3 in place (hopefully I did it right), https://gyazo.com/bf0816763e9d62a9bccef088bb3a3b69

However, I'm still getting the same errors when I run my main function.

Comment: @SilviuTofan: If you do not pass the `-w` switch to `2to3` it will not modify the file. See [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html#using-2to3): "Writing the changes back is enabled with the -w flag".

Comment: Oh, sorry about that. I did it passing -w and still same result. However when I modified `range` back into `xrange` manually, it did modify that. But the function itself is still working. Could there be something wrong with the function itself? That's highly unlikely though, as the reference seems to be credible enough.

Comment: I get no errors when using `hv3` with `python3`. It sounds like you are still having problems with `2to3`.

Comment: I just tried it again with the original example, and it does indeed work now. It's just not working for my existing algorithm, so I'll guess I'll go and figure that one out. Well, try at least. Thanks a bunch for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use 2to3 and replace the following line of hv.py to fix TypeError:

`decorated.sort()`

to

`sorted(decorated, key=lambda n: n[0])`

It should work like python2.